# How do I find the SUM of the following rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query in SQL :

```
SELECT LOCATION_CODE AS "Location",
       AUTHORIZATION_STATUS AS "Authorization Status",
       COUNT(authorization_status) AS "Requisition Lines Count", 
       imcb.SEGMENT1 AS "CATEGORY"
FROM apps.po_requisition_headers_all   prha  
JOIN apps.po_requisition_lines_all prla
    ON  prla.REQUISITION_HEADER_ID = prha.REQUISITION_HEADER_ID
    AND (prha.CANCEL_FLAG = 'N' OR prha.CANCEL_FLAG IS NULL )
JOIN INV.MTL_CATEGORIES_B imcb
    ON prla.category_id = imcb.category_id    
JOIN HR.PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F P
    ON P.person_id = prha.preparer_id  
JOIN apps.HR_LOCATIONS ahl
    ON prla.deliver_to_location_id =  ahl.location_id
JOIN apps.FND_USER  afu
    ON p.person_id = afu.employee_id
WHERE prla.CREATION_DATE >= '13-JUN-14'    
  AND P.effective_start_date >= 
                    ALL (SELECT p_temp.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
                         FROM HR.PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F p_temp
                          WHERE P.PERSON_ID = p_temp.PERSON_ID)
  AND P.current_employee_flag = 'Y' 

                 /*    AND AUTHORIZATION_STATUS = 'APPROVED'      */

  AND ahl.country IN ( 'US', 'CA', 'MX' ) /* countries in NA */ 
  AND imcb.SEGMENT1 = 'NONBOM'
GROUP BY imcb.SEGMENT1 , authorization_status,  LOCATION_CODE
ORDER BY Location_code ASC
```

And it yields the following output :
[image]

However, I would like it to have the total Count for a single location, regardless of Authorization Status. So , it should look like so :

```
Liberty Lake             826
```

Rather than

```
Liberty Lake             767
Liberty Lake             29
Liberty Lake             29
etc
```

How do I generate this result? I tried adding in a `SUM` like so:

```
sum(authorization_status),
```

but this gives me the following error:

> ORA-01722:  invalid number

Comment: Have you tried the SUM aggregate function?

Comment: I tried but I get an error : `ORA-01722: invalid number`

Comment: Remove authorization_status from Group By clause and from Select it would give total count for a single location regardless of Authorization status.

Comment: isn't it just a case of just having location_code and the count(*) in the select column list, and grouping by location_code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `group by rollup` instead of just `group by`

You'll get the current summaaries you have now plus rolled up summaries:

```
GROUP BY imcb.SEGMENT1,  LOCATION_CODE, ROLLUP (authorization_status)
```

If you don't want any of the more detailed summaries, then remove authorization_status from both your select and group by lists.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the aggregate function `SUM` on a text field, which is why you are getting that error. `SUM` is for adding numeric values together. `COUNT` is used to count the occurrences of rows in that grouping scope. What I think you actually want to do is remove Authorization status from your query, so it would actually be:

```
SELECT LOCATION_CODE AS "Location",
       COUNT(authorization_status) AS "Requisition Lines Count", 
       imcb.SEGMENT1 AS "CATEGORY"
FROM apps.po_requisition_headers_all   prha  
JOIN apps.po_requisition_lines_all prla
    ON  prla.REQUISITION_HEADER_ID = prha.REQUISITION_HEADER_ID
    AND (prha.CANCEL_FLAG = 'N' OR prha.CANCEL_FLAG IS NULL )
JOIN INV.MTL_CATEGORIES_B imcb
    ON prla.category_id = imcb.category_id    
JOIN HR.PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F P
    ON P.person_id = prha.preparer_id  
JOIN apps.HR_LOCATIONS ahl
    ON prla.deliver_to_location_id =  ahl.location_id
JOIN apps.FND_USER  afu
    ON p.person_id = afu.employee_id
WHERE prla.CREATION_DATE >= '13-JUN-14'    
  AND P.effective_start_date >= 
                    ALL (SELECT p_temp.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
                         FROM HR.PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F p_temp
                          WHERE P.PERSON_ID = p_temp.PERSON_ID)
  AND P.current_employee_flag = 'Y' 

                 /*    AND AUTHORIZATION_STATUS = 'APPROVED'      */

  AND ahl.country IN ( 'US', 'CA', 'MX' ) /* countries in NA */ 
  AND imcb.SEGMENT1 = 'NONBOM'
GROUP BY imcb.SEGMENT1 ,  LOCATION_CODE
ORDER BY Location_code ASC
```

Note that I removed it from both my `SELECT` list and my `GROUP BY` clause.